# Typescript won't allow me to access object property

Tags: typescript, object, key

I have defined an object:

```
const parsers = {
  belgianMobile: (input: string) =>
    input.replace(/^(0032|0)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1$2 $3 $4 $5').replace('0032', '+ 32 '),
};
```

and I now want to access this object's property via a key (for later when I add multiple parsers):

```
const clean = cleanNumber(text);
  const [key] = Object.entries(validations).find(([key, regex]) => regex.test(clean));
  return ((parsers[key](text)) && parsers[key](clean)) || text;
```

but this is the error typescript throws my way:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ belgianMobile: (input: string) => string; }'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ belgianMobile: (input: string) => string; }'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you need to type the object itself from which you want to read it out like so:

```
const validations: { [key: string]: RegExp } = {
  belgianMobile: /^(0032|0)4\d{8}$/,
};

const parsers: { [key: string]: (input: string) => string } = {
  belgianMobile: input =>
    input.replace(/^(0032|0)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1$2 $3 $4 $5').replace('0032', '+ 32 '),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From above i think you want something like this.

```
const message: string = 'hello world';
const parsers1 = [{
  belgianMobile: (input: string) =>
    input.replace(/^(0032|0)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1$2 $3 $4 $5').replace('0032', '+ 32 '),
},{
  belgianMobile1: (input: string) =>
    input.replace(/^(0032|0)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1$2 $3 $4 $5').replace('0032', '+ 32 '),
}];
console.log(parsers1[0].belgianMobile(message));
console.log(parsers1[1].belgianMobile1(message));
```